# Finding all slices delimited by two elements in Scala `List`

Tags: scala, list, slice, regular-language

In Scala, what would be the right way of selecting elements of a list based on the position of two elements? Suppose I have the list below and I would like to select all the elements between 2 and 7, including them (note: not greater than/smaller than, but the elements that come after 2 and before 7 in the list):

```
scala> val l = List(1, 14, 2, 17, 35, 9, 12, 7, 9, 40)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 14, 2, 17, 35, 9, 12, 7, 9, 40)

scala> def someMethod(l: List[Int], from: Int, to: Int) : List[Int] = {
     | // some code here
     | }
someMethod: (l: List[Int], from: Int, to: Int)List[Int]

scala> someMethod(l, 2, 7)
res0: List[Int] = List(2, 17, 35, 9, 12, 7)
```

Expected output:

- For lists that don't contain 2 and/or 7: an empty list
- Input: `(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8)`; Output: `(2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 7)`
- Input: `(1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 7, 7, 8)`; Output: `(2, 3, 4, 7)`
- Input: `(1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8)`; Output: `((2, 3, 4, 7), (2, 3, 5, 7))`

Comment: What have you tried?, Any ideas? - Also, if there are multiple occurrences of `from` or `to`, what should happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too bad that the regex-engines work only with strings, not with general lists - would be really nice if you could find all matches for something like `L.*?R` with two arbitrary delimiters `L` and `R`. Since it doesn't work with regex, you have to build a little automaton yourself. Here is one way to do it:

```
@annotation.tailrec 
def findDelimitedSlices[A](
  xs: List[A],
  l: A,
  r: A,
  revAcc: List[List[A]] = Nil
): List[List[A]] = {
  xs match {
    case h :: t => if (h == l) {
      val idx = xs.indexOf(r)
      if (idx >= 0) {
        val (s, rest) = xs.splitAt(idx + 1)
        findDelimitedSlices(rest, l, r, s :: revAcc)
      } else {
        revAcc.reverse
      }
    } else {
      findDelimitedSlices(t, l, r, revAcc)
    }
    case Nil => revAcc.reverse
  }
}
```

Input:

```
for (example <- List(
  List(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8),
  List(1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 7, 7, 8),
  List(1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8)
)) {
  println(findDelimitedSlices(example, 2, 7))
}
```

Output:

```
List(List(2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 7))
List(List(2, 3, 4, 7))
List(List(2, 3, 4, 7), List(2, 3, 5, 7))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`slice`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#slice(from:Int,until:Int):List[A]):

```
@ l.slice(2, 7)
res1: List[Int] = List(2, 17, 35, 9, 12)

@ l.slice(2, 8)
res2: List[Int] = List(2, 17, 35, 9, 12, 7)
```

Comment: Thanks @Andy, your high reputation shows your collaborative spirit. After doing my search, and being familiar with `slice`, I dont think it solves my problem since I would need to know the position of the elements in the list in advance.

Comment: I think a mix of `slice` and `indexOf` would probably work best for this case, with the caveat that there are some edge cases in case 2 and/or 7 repeat throughout the list. I'll work something out.

Comment: @Phil `l.slice(l.indexOf(2), l.indexOf(7) + 1)` but only if you are sure 2 is in the List.

Comment: Right, that's what I was thinking. I am brand new to Scala, but have a lot of Java experience, so my automatic reaction is to write Java style code, check for preexistence of elements in a collection, etc. (very verbose) so I was wondering the best way in Scala to do this straight with collection methods. I think `slice` with `indexOf` will probably work for most cases, now I want to dig into the edge cases. Thanks again.